# Simplify Query with Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have this code:

```
@messages = Message.where(["user_id = ? AND receiver_uuid = ? OR user_id = ? AND receiver_uuid = ?", current_user.id, @friend_user[0].id, @friend_user[0].id, current_user.id])
```

I need to look for the relationship between the two ids, in 2 columns.

My create method:

```
    def send_message
        @message = Message.new(user: current_user, receiver_uuid: message_params[:receiver_uuid], body: message_params[:body])        
        respond_to do |format|
            if @message.save
                flash[:notice] = "Mensagem enviada com sucesso!"
                format.html { redirect_to messenger_path(message_params[:receiver_uuid]) }             
            else
                flash[:alert] = "Erro ao enviar a mensagem!"
                format.html { redirect_to messenger_path(message_params[:receiver_uuid]) }             
            end
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for simplification, start by using models instead of ids in your query. You can do smth like this:

`@messages = Message.where(user: current_user, receiver: @friend_user).or(Message.where(user: @friend_user, receiver: current_user))`

Or better yet:

`@messages = current_user.messages.where(receiver: @friend_user).or(@friend_user.messages.where(receiver: current_user))`

Of course, this assumes that your Message model has a `:receiver` relation, but there's no reason why it shouldn't have it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it...

In your model:

```
# message.rb
class Message
  scope :by_user_id, -> (user_id) { where(user_id: user_id) }
  scope :by_receiver_uuid, -> (receiver_uuid) { where(receiver_uuid: receiver_uuid) }
end
```

And then you can do:

```
# messages_controller.rb (or wherever)
ids = [current_user.id, @friend_user[0].id]
messages = Message.by_user_id( ids ) | Message.by_receiver_uuid( ids )
```